# How can I hide the bottom tab bar on a specific screen (react-navigation 3.x)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I used the createBottomTabNavigator, but I can't hide the bottom app bar on a specific screen

```
const StackHome = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: Home,
    Autor: Autor,
    Publicacion: Publicacion,
    Comentarios: {
      screen: Comentarios,
      navigationOptions:{
        // this should do the work, but it doesn't
        tabBarVisible: false
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I got a solution that works, the component would be like this

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import Home from "./Home";
import Autor from "./Profile";
import Publicacion from "./Publicacion";
import Comentarios from "./Comentarios";

const StackHome = createStackNavigator({
  Home: Home,
  Autor: Autor,
  Publicacion: Publicacion,
  Comentarios: Comentarios
});

// This does the trick
StackHome.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let tabBarVisible;
  if (navigation.state.routes.length > 1) {
    navigation.state.routes.map(route => {
      if (route.routeName === "Comentarios") {
        tabBarVisible = false;
      } else {
        tabBarVisible = true;
      }
    });
  }

  return {
    tabBarVisible
  };
};

export default StackHome;
```

Answer (score 2):

if your screen is also nested stack navigation and the parent is a bottom navigation, there is a navigation prop on options function you can use. e.g.:

```
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const Home = () => (
  <BottomTab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Explore"
    tabBarOptions={{
      activeTintColor: "#00B0F0",
    }}
  >
    <BottomTab.Screen
      name="Explore"
      component={Explore}
      options={({ navigation }) => {
        const { routes, index } = navigation.dangerouslyGetState();
        const { state: exploreState } = routes[index];
        let tabBarVisible = true;
        if (exploreState) {
          const { routes: exploreRoutes, index: exploreIndex } = exploreState;
          const exploreActiveRoute = exploreRoutes[exploreIndex];
          if (exploreActiveRoute.name === "RewardDetail") tabBarVisible = false;
        }
        return {
          tabBarVisible,
          title: "Explore",
          tabBarLabel: "Explore",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <AntDesign name="search1" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        };
      }}
    />
```

note that you will have to use if conditions there as props are not present when not activated, just simply do as my example. There is also a suggestion from the documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/ personally i would do that if there's no option for tabBarVisible usage.

Comment: I am using react-navigation v5 and this has no effect, in my case `Expore` is a StackNavigator

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it should not... you are hidint the tab bar ... in a stacknavigator... you can do something similar to [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#a-tab-navigator-contains-a-stack-and-you-want-to-hide-the-tab-bar-on-specific-screens). but i don't know how you would hide it on one screen

```
const StackHome = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: Home,
    Autor: Autor,
    Publicacion: Publicacion,
    Comentarios: Comentarios
  }
);
StackHome navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let tabBarVisible = true;

  if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
    tabBarVisible = false;
  }

  return {
    tabBarVisible,
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! your code works perfectly hidding all the app bar, but I can't get it work to hide on a specific screen yet

Comment: How can i do it in V5?

Answer (score 1):

```
const routesWithNoTabNavigator = ['nameOfYourRoute', 'nameOfYourOtherRoute'];

<yourStackHere>.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let tabBarVisible = true;
  const currentRoute = 
        navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.routes.length -1].routeName;
  if(routesWithNoTabNavigator.includes(currentRoute)) {
      tabBarVisible = false;
  }

  return {
   tabBarVisible,
  };
};
```

Comment: Please update your question to include a description of your solution so that it is clearer for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
if(navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index].routeName == "Comentarios"){
tabBarVisible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a useEffect. When inside the specific screen access the parent navigation with navigation.getParent() and then use the method .setOptions() as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigation.getParent().setOptions({
        tabBarStyle: {
            display: 'none'
        }
    })
    return () => {
        navigation.getParent().setOptions({
            tabBarStyle: {
                display: 'flex'
            }
        })
    }
})
```

when exiting the specific screen make sure to step the tab bar style to flex. If there's a small delay in bringing back the tab bar after leaving the specific screen you can just setOptions with a go back button which you should have in the absence of a bottom tab.