# When using both: Stack Navigator and BottomTab Navigator how do I hide the bottom tab when inside a Stack Navigation Screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am having a Bottom Navigation with 2 Tabs so far (Home & Messages). When inside Messages I can press on a User to get navigated to the **ChatScreen** which is a Screen from the **Stack Navigator**. In that **ChatScreen** I want to **hide** the **BottomTab**. I know that it is possible to hide it by adding `tabBarStyle: { display: "none" }` to the `<Tab.Screen />` but this doesn't work for the **ChatScreen** since it is not a **Tab.Screen**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer, StackActions} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Home from './app/Screens/Home';
import CommentSection from './app/Screens/CommentSection';
import MessageScreen from './app/Screens/MessageScreen';
import ChatScreen from './app/Screens/ChatScreen';
import NavigationHeader from './app/global/headers/NavigationHeader';
import SendOffer from './app/Screens/SendOffer';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import ChatScreenHeader from './app/Screens/ChatScreen/ChatScreenHeader';

const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const HomeStackScreen = () => {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          // header: AppBar,
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="CommentSection"
        component={CommentSection}
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Home',
          // animationTypeForReplace: 'push',
          animation: 'slide_from_bottom',
        }}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="SendOffer"
        component={SendOffer}
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Home',
          animation: 'slide_from_right',
        }}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="ChatScreen"
        component={ChatScreen} //HIDE BottomTab INSIDE THIS COMPONENT
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Messages',
          animation: 'slide_from_right',
        }}
      />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
};

const MessageStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const MessageStackScreen = () => {
  return (
    <MessageStack.Navigator>
      <MessageStack.Screen
        name="MessageScreen"
        component={MessageScreen}
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Messages',
          animation: 'slide_from_right',
        }}
      />
      <MessageStack.Screen
        name="ChatScreen"
        component={ChatScreen} //HIDE BottomTab INSIDE THIS COMPONENT
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Messages',
          headerShown: false,
          animation: 'slide_from_right',
        }}
      />
    </MessageStack.Navigator>
  );
};

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Messages">
        <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeStackScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
        name="Messages"
        component={MessageStackScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarLabel: 'Messages',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="chat" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
          // tabBarStyle: { display: "none" }
        }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70153935/12029941) by [@Escaper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12657014/escaper) from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56745881/how-to-hide-bottom-navigation-bar-on-a-specific-screen-in-react-native)

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigation.getParent()?.setOptions({ tabBarStyle: { display: "none" }});
    return () => navigation.getParent()?.setOptions({ tabBarStyle: undefined });
  }, [navigation]);
```

Comment: please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75287020/how-to-use-stack-navigation-or-tab-bar-navigation-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

You could use `createNavigationContainerRef` to check the current route name via the `getCurrentRoute()` function inside the component that creates the `BottomTabNavigator` and then use `tabBarStyle` conditionally as you have suggested.

This could look as follows.

```js
import { createNavigationContainerRef } from "@react-navigation/native"

const ref = createNavigationContainerRef();

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const hide = "ChatScreen" === ref.current?.getCurrentRoute()?.name
   
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Messages">
        <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeStackScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
        name="Messages"
        component={MessageStackScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarLabel: 'Messages',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="chat" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
          tabBarStyle: { display: hide ? "none" : "flex" }
        }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looked promising but ref.current always returned null. Tried to figure out how to make this solution working but instead I found a great solution that worked for me from another post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56745881/how-to-hide-bottom-navigation-bar-on-a-specific-screen-in-react-native) by @Escaper (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70153935/12029941)

Comment: Interesting, I have a project in which we are doing this. Well, maybe there is a difference that I haven't understood yet. I'm glad you have found a solution that works for you! +1