# Hidding tab bar bottom navigation from certain route screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabbar, react-navigation-v6

I'm attempting to remove the tab bar bottom navigator from certain pages from my application. I have performed several searches with indication to use `display:none` or other methods, but they are not seeming to work. I have several nested routes inside of the Main route.
This is the tab route:

```
export function TabRoutes({ navigation }: any) {
  const { Navigator, Screen } = createBottomTabNavigator();
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <Navigator
      initialRouteName="FeedRt"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarActiveTintColor: theme.colors.primary,
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: theme.colors.tabBarBackground,
          position: 'absolute',
          borderTopRightRadius: 16,
          borderTopLeftRadius: 16,
          borderColor: '#9E9E9E',
          borderWidth: RFValue(0.5),
          borderStyle: 'solid',
          bottom: -10,
          height: 90,
          paddingHorizontal: 16,
          // tabBarStyle: { display: 'none' }
        },
      }}
    >
      <Screen
        key="FeedRt"
        name="FeedRt"
        component={FeedRoutes}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabBarIconAndText text="Home" focused={focused} icon="Home" />
          ),
          tabBarLabel: '',
        }}
      />
      <Screen
        key="SearchRt"
        name="SearchRt"
        component={SearchRoutes}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabBarIconAndText text="Search" focused={focused} icon="Search" />
          ),
          tabBarLabel: '',
        }}
      />
      <Screen
        key="CreatePosts"
        name="CreatePosts"
        component={EmptyScreen}
        listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
          tabPress: (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
          },
        })}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <ToolTip navigation={navigation}>
              <View
                style={{
                  marginTop: 10,
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary,
                  width: 40,
                  height: 40,
                  borderRadius: 20,
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}
              >
                <PlusSVG />
              </View>
            </ToolTip>
          ),
          tabBarLabel: '',
        }}
      />
      <Screen
        key="Shorts"
        name="Shorts"
        component={Shorts}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabBarIconAndText text="Shorts" focused={focused} icon="Shorts" />
          ),
          tabBarLabel: '',
        }}
      />
      <Screen
        key="Profile"
        name="Profile"
        children={() => <Profile navigation={navigation} myProfile={true} />}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabBarIconAndText text="Profile" focused={focused} icon="Profile" />
          ),
          tabBarLabel: '',
        }}
      />
    </Navigator>
  );
}
```

I want to remove the tab bar showing in the Comments from the FeedRoute

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

// Screens
import { Feed } from '../screens/FeedScreens/Feed';
import { Comments } from '../screens/FeedScreens/Comments';

export function FeedRoutes() {
  const { Navigator, Screen } = createStackNavigator();

  return (
    <Navigator initialRouteName="Posts" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Screen key="Posts" name="Posts" component={Feed} />
      <Screen key="Comments" name="Comments" component={Comments} />
    </Navigator>
  );
}
```

And I have this App route witch calls the Main (Tab route):

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

// Screens
import { TabRoutes } from './tab.routes';
import { PostRoutes } from './post.routes';
import { FeedRoutes } from './feed.routes';

export function AppRoutes() {
  const { Navigator, Screen } = createStackNavigator();

  return (
    <Navigator initialRouteName="Main" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Screen key="Main" name="Main" component={TabRoutes} />
      <Screen key="Post" name="Post" component={PostRoutes} />
    </Navigator>
  );
}
```

Want to remove it from this screen:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide bottom navigation bar on a specific screen in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56745881/how-to-hide-bottom-navigation-bar-on-a-specific-screen-in-react-native)

Comment: @Abe How would I apply this into my system, I don't believe this is the answer since I have nested navigators. This seems to be for RNV4

Comment: The principle is the same. Create a stack outside your tab navigator, and put the screens you want to hide the navigator on into that stack. Navigating to that stack will hide the tabs

Comment: Could you format that into a answer?

Comment: Sorry, format what into a question? I was summarizing the strategy you can follow

Comment: Create an answer with the formatted code so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just move `Comments` route from `FeedRoutes` to `AppRoutes`.
2. replace `component={FeedRoutes}` to `component={Feed}` in `TabRoutes`.

There is no need to create `FeedRoutes` component.

See more https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/

Comment: I believe I have a more complex structure than this.

Comment: Just move `Comments` route from FeedRoutes to AppRoutes and replace `component={FeedRoutes}` to `component={Feed}` in TabRoutes. There is no need to create FeedRoutes component.

Comment: That works as expected, could you update your above answer so I can accept it